# pandas drop_duplicates on blocks of duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I am trying to find an elegant solution to turn a complete time series of slowly moving data into a compressed form that I can then use with a pd.merge_asof.

For example below data frame:

```
2023-01-01  A
2023-01-02  B
2023-01-03  B
2023-01-04  B
2023-01-05  C
2023-01-06  C
2023-01-07  A
2023-01-08  B
```

What I want to achieve is to keep the first record of a duplicate block, i.e.

```
2023-01-01  A
2023-01-02  B
2023-01-05  C
2023-01-07  A
2023-01-08  B
```

What comes to mind is `df.sort_index().drop_duplicates(keep='first')` but it does a global groupby and doesn't account for `A` and `B` showing up again later.

Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your 2nd column called `name` (for ex.), short approach with [`pandas.DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) function to capture the 1st unique value in each consecutive group (walking down):

```
df[df['name'] != df['name'].shift(1)]
```

---

```
           name
2023-01-01    A
2023-01-02    B
2023-01-05    C
2023-01-07    A
2023-01-08    B
```

Comment: This works well :). But I have a little wrench to throw in.
If I add a column 'category' and I want to treat these independently, i.e. apply this logic for each category, I guess I could go along the lines of:

`
result = []
for cat, cat_df in df.groupby('category'):
    # apply logic and add to result
`

but that seems a little clunky. wonder if there's a neat 1 liner.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `shift` function to compare each row with the previous row and then check for changes in the value column. Now you can use boolean indexing to select rows where the changes occurred.

```py
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df["change"] = df["value"] != df["value"].shift()
df = df[df["change"]]

df =df.drop(columns=["change"])
```

Output:

```
        date value
0 2023-01-01     A
1 2023-01-02     B
4 2023-01-05     C
6 2023-01-07     A
7 2023-01-08     B
```